# Folder delete in Fork Repo from Master Repo cause conflict when trying to sync

Tags: git

I created a fork of master repository then deleted one folder in fork repository and committed it, Now when I pull master into fork to keep it up to date and there is a change in  that folder file which was deleted from fork repository it gives conflict

I don't want that folder in fork repository, what is the solution in git?

Comment: give more information

Answer (score 0):

Well.... if you want the directory gone *and* there are changes on those files on the branch that you forked from, what else can git do other than tell you there's a conflict?

If this is *really* bothering you, you might consider using a bash alias or a script that can do the merge and check conflicts in that directory so that it removes them if they pop up.